# Getting 502 while deploy a Laravel app to AWS Elasticbeanstalk with Nginx

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Laravel application, and able to up docker with these config files, while I am deployed to eb but keep getting error 502. Please let me know if you any other information from me. Thank you very much.

Here are my config files:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: php
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - redis
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    networks:
      - app-network

  mysql:
    image: mysql:8
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=app
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_USER=app
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - app-network

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./:/var/www
    depends_on:
      - php
    networks:
      - app-network

  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - app-network

volumes:
  db-data:

#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm
ARG envfile

# Copy source code
RUN rm -rf /var/www/*
ADD . /var/www/

# Setup laravel
WORKDIR /var/www

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    libzip-dev \
    zip \
    unzip \
    cron \
    sed

RUN docker-php-ext-configure zip --with-libzip

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql zip

RUN docker-php-ext-install pcntl

RUN curl --silent --show-error https://getcomposer.org/installer | php && \
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

## Configure nginx
RUN rm -rf /var/www/.env && \
    composer install --no-dev --no-interaction --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader && \
    touch /var/log/cron.log && \
    chown www-data:www-data /var/log/cron.log && \
    echo '* * * * * www-data php /var/www/artisan schedule:run >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1' > /etc/cron.d/laravel-cron && \
    chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/laravel-cron && \
    touch /etc/cron.d/laravel-cron && \
    chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/ && \
    chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/storage && \
    chown -R root:www-data /var/www/storage/logs && \
    chmod -R 775 /var/www/storage && \
    chmod -R 775 /var/www/bootstrap/cache && \
    crontab /etc/cron.d/laravel-cron


# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

**/docker/default.conf**

```
server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:80;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;
  root /var/www/public; # default Laravel's entry point for all requests

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  location / {
    # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
    try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass php:9000; # address of a fastCGI server
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

Cat my ec2 Nginx error log file

```
2019/09/15 05:21:18 [error] 4445#0: *9 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 202.184.195.155, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.3:9000/favicon.ico", host: "xxx.riaxasvw2y.ap-southeast-1.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "http://xxx.riaxasvw2y.ap-southeast-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/"
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-43-158 ~]$ cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Comment: check `ls /var/www` in nginx container also nginc.conf